# How to set up permalinks properly in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, https, phpmyadmin

I recently migrated from Bluehost to Digital Ocean for my hosting. The only problem is I was using the HTTPS while I cloned the site with the duplicator plugin, So after researching for a while, I was able to access my admin panel but all the links on the page seems to be messed up. Let's say mydomain.com is now currently pointing to my website and the dashboard is accessible via mydomain.com/wp-admin. but clicking any of the links on my homepage exposes my IP address and takes me to 139.59.xx.xx/any_internal_link. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you fix the issue in the end ?

Answer (score 0):

- check you `wp_option` table for `siteurl` and `home` value, update it with your new site URL if needed
- go to your dashboard, permalink, and hit the save button (without changing anything)
- if you configured yourself your apache/nginx vhost, please post your configuration.